# WordNet - Parts-Of-Speech required?

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

To figure out if the two words are SYNONYMS (SIMILAR_TO), do I need to find the Parts-Of-Speech for the two words first? Can I do this in a single 'operation' in the WordNet or will I have to loop through the senses first for each word?

Comment: Are you using the wordnet itself, or a library like jwnl?

Comment: @user3639557 - I am using JWNL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synsets are categorized according to the POS. So there is no way to avoid it.